# What do I need to use an XBOX 360 with my PC monitor and speakers?

Tags: xbox360

I've been thinking about getting an XBOX 360, mostly for games on XBLA or some exlusive titles, since they're relatively cheap now to get used.

But I'm a student and live in a small apartment that has no TV, and no place to put a new TV (money to buy one wouldn't be a problem), so I've been thinking to use the console with my PC monitor and my speakers.

My monitor only has HDMI and VGA input (no direct DVI), so I'm guessing I somehow need to split the audio and video signals coming from the XBox (or does the XBox have a direct 720p VGA output + external connectors for my speakers?).

What do I need to make this happen?

Comment: I could've sworn that the XBox 360 did HDMI...

Comment: It does, but a monitor only understands pictures. I still want audio :)

Comment: Internet also to download the games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My xbox360 elite (old style) is hooked up via HDMI to a tv no problem and I assume wouldn't be a problem with a monitor on HDMI, and then you can probably hook up sound direct from the monitor to your pc speakers? if your monitor doesn't suppose the xbox comes with an adaptor that goes to stereo red and white speaker hookups that can then be converted to 3.5mm speaker output.
just make sure you get an xbox with HDMI (I don't know if they all have it or if the cheaper ones don't!)
all these adaptor and stuff if they are needed shouldn't set you back much!

Comment: Thanks, but my monitor does indeed have no connectors to any external speakers. What kind of adapters do I need exactly? I have a hard time googleing.

Comment: http://www.play.com/Games/Xbox360/4-/719745/Official-Xbox-360-VGA-HD-AV-Cable/Product.html    -    plus an adaptor to the right output for audio if u need it!

Answer (score 1):

To make this happen you will need a HDMI audio adapter for Xbox, a 3.5mm audio connector (RCA-headphones), speakers or headphones, a HDMI cable and the screen with a HDMI input.

View [Connect your Xbox 360 console to a sound system](http://support.xbox.com/en-AU/xbox-360/connections/connect-sound-system) for connecting an Xbox via HDMI.

People using DVI, the same answer as above although, you will need a DVI-HDMI switch. They are about 10-20$AU in any computer store.

For people using VGA, you will need a VGA HD AV Cable for Xbox. View [Connect an Xbox 360 S console or an original Xbox 360 console to a TV](http://support.xbox.com/en-AU/xbox-360/system/connect-xbox-360-console-tv) for instruction.
Alternatively, most 3rd party intercoolers have vga connectors too.